# How can I allow user to change their key for play?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

This is my code for a tron-like game:

```
const TAILLE_SNAKE = 10;
const souris = document.getElementById("bouton");

class jeuSnake {
  constructor(Idcanvas, tailleSnake) {
    this.canvas = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
    document.onkeydown = this.KeyboardEvent.bind(this);

    this.tailleSnake = tailleSnake;
    this.largeur = document.getElementById("canvas").width;
    this.hauteur = document.getElementById("canvas").height;

    this.Snakes = [];
    this.Positions = [];
  }

  ajouteSnake(Snake) {
    this.Snakes.push(Object.assign({}, Snake));
  }

  KeyboardEvent(e) {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.Snakes.length; i++) {
      const Snake = this.Snakes[i];

      if (Snake.active != true) {
        continue;
      }

      var nouvelleDirection;
      if (e.keyCode === Snake.touchesClavier.haut) {
        nouvelleDirection = { x: 0, y: -1 };
      } else if (e.keyCode === Snake.touchesClavier.bas) {
        nouvelleDirection = { x: 0, y: 1 };
      } else if (e.keyCode === Snake.touchesClavier.gauche) {
        nouvelleDirection = { x: -1, y: 0 };
      } else if (e.keyCode === Snake.touchesClavier.droite) {
        nouvelleDirection = { x: 1, y: 0 };
      } else{
        continue;
      }
      // Si on retourne dans la direction d'où l'on vient, on ne fait rien;
      if (
        (nouvelleDirection.x === Snake.direction.x &&
          nouvelleDirection.y !== Snake.direction.y) ||
        (nouvelleDirection.y === Snake.direction.y &&
          nouvelleDirection.x !== Snake.direction.x)
      ) {
        continue;
      }

      Snake.direction = nouvelleDirection;
    }
  }

  perdantSnake(Snake) {
    if (
      Snake.position.x < 0 ||
      Snake.position.y < 0 ||
      Snake.position.x >= this.largeur ||
      Snake.position.y >= this.hauteur
    ) {
      return true;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < this.Positions.length; i++) {
      const position = this.Positions[i].point;

      if (
        Snake.position.x - (this.tailleSnake - 1) / 2 <= position.x &&
        position.x <= Snake.position.x + (this.tailleSnake - 1) / 2 + 1 &&
        Snake.position.y - (this.tailleSnake - 1) / 2 <= position.y &&
        position.y <= Snake.position.y + (this.tailleSnake - 1) / 2 + 1
      ) {
        return true;
      }
    }

    return false;
  }

  gagnantSnake(nouvellePos, nouvelleCouleur) {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.Positions.length; i++) {
      const position = this.Positions[i];

      if (position.point === nouvellePos) {
        position.couleur = nouvelleCouleur;
        return;
      }
    }

    // Pas de position enregistrée pour ce point, on en crée une nouvelle;
    this.Positions.push({
      point: nouvellePos,
      couleur: nouvelleCouleur
    });
  }

  terminer() {
    const joueursActif = this.Snakes.reduce(
      (a, v) => a + (v.active ? true : false),
      false
    );
    return joueursActif <= 1;

  }

  gagnant() {
    if (this.terminer() != true) {
      return null;
    }

    return this.Snakes.find(e => e.active);
  }

  maj() {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.Snakes.length; i++) {
      const Snake = this.Snakes[i];

      if (Snake.active != true) {
        continue;
      }

      const precPos = Snake.position;

      // On met à jour les positons des snakes
      // à côté des enregistrements cases
      Snake.position = {
        x: Math.min(
          Snake.position.x + Snake.direction.x * this.tailleSnake,
          this.largeur - this.tailleSnake / 2
        ),
        y: Math.min(
          Snake.position.y + Snake.direction.y * this.tailleSnake,
          this.hauteur - this.tailleSnake / 2
        )
      };

      // On vérifie si le joueur est mort et on dessine la case;
      // donc:
      if (this.perdantSnake(Snake) != true) {
        this.gagnantSnake(Snake.position, Snake.couleur);
        this.gagnantSnake(precPos, Snake.tracecouleur);
      } else {
        Snake.position = precPos;
        Snake.active = false;
        this.gagnantSnake(Snake.position, "yellow");
      }
    }

    // On finit par dessiner le canvas avec la maj;
    this.draw();
  }

  draw() {
    // On dessine tous les canvas avec couleur;
    this.canvas.fillStyle = "#E0E0E0";
    this.canvas.fillRect(0, 0, this.largeur, this.hauteur);

    // On dessine toutes les positions enregistrées;
    for (var i = 0; i < this.Positions.length; i++) {
      const { point: position, couleur } = this.Positions[i];

      this.canvas.fillStyle = couleur;
      this.canvas.fillRect(
        position.x - (this.tailleSnake) / 2,
        position.y - (this.tailleSnake) / 2,
        this.tailleSnake,
        this.tailleSnake
      );
    }
  }
}

Joueurs = [
  {
    nomJoueur: "Joueur 1",
    position: {
      x: 0,
      y: 0
    },
    direction: { x: 0, y: -1 },
    couleur: "blue",
    tracecouleur: "#0083FF",
    touchesClavier: {
      haut: 90,
      bas: 87,
      gauche: 81,
      droite: 68
    },
    active: true,
    score: 0
  },
  {
    nomJoueur: "Joueur 2",
    position: {
      x: 0,
      y: 0
    },
    direction: { x: 1, y: 0 },
    couleur: "#8B0000",
    tracecouleur: "#f00",
    touchesClavier: {
      haut: 79,
      bas: 190,
      gauche: 75,
      droite: 77
    },
    active: true,
    score: 0
  },

];

function chargerJeu() {
  const jeu_snake = new jeuSnake("canvas", TAILLE_SNAKE);
  souris.disabled = true;

  for (var i = 0; i < Joueurs.length; i++) {
    Joueurs[0].position = {
      x: 10,
      y: 280
    };
    Joueurs[1].position = {
      x: 10,
      y: 300
    };

    directions = [
      { x: 1, y: 0 },
      { x: 1, y: 0 },
    ];

    Joueurs[i].direction =
      directions[Math.floor(Math.random() * directions.length)];

    jeu_snake.ajouteSnake(Joueurs[i]);
  }

  var score = Joueurs.map(e => {
    return "<li><strong>"+e.nomJoueur+" : "+e.score+"</strong></li>";
  });

  document.getElementById("score-liste").innerHTML = score;

  return jeu_snake;
}

var jeu_snake = chargerJeu();
var date = performance.now();

function main() {
  jeu_snake.maj();
  if (jeu_snake.terminer() == true) {
    const gagnant = jeu_snake.gagnant();
    if (gagnant != null) {
      for (var i = 0; i < Joueurs.length; i++) {
        if (Joueurs[i].nomJoueur === gagnant.nomJoueur) {
          Joueurs[i].score += 1;
        }
        if(Joueurs[i].score == 3){
          jeu_snake = chargerJeu();
          text = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
          text.font = "100px Calibri" ;
          text.fillText(gagnant.nomJoueur+" a gagné !", 30, 300)
          souris.disabled = false;
          jeu_snake.terminer() = false;
        }

      }

    }

    jeu_snake = chargerJeu();
    date = performance.now();
  }


  // On diminue le temps toutes les 2 secondes
  const tempsEcoule = performance.now() - date;
  const accelerationTemps = 200 - TAILLE_SNAKE * Math.floor(tempsEcoule / 1500);
  setTimeout(function() {
    main();
  }, accelerationTemps);
}

souris.addEventListener("click", function(){
  Joueurs[0].score = 0;
  Joueurs[1].score = 0;
  jeu_snake=chargerJeu();
  main();
});

main();
```

I configure some keyCode by default but I want, like I said in the title, allow player to configure their own keyCode I don't know how to do this... Can you please help me?

Edit: I tried to do lot of things, my last try is about that:

```
function changerTouches(event){
  joueurs[0].touchesClavier.haut = document.getElementById("j1h").keyCode;
  joueurs[0].touchesClavier.bas = document.getElementById("j1h").keyCode;
  joueurs[0].touchesClavier.gauche = document.getElementById("j1h").keyCode;
  joueurs[0].touchesClavier.droite = document.getElementById("j1h").keyCode;
  console.log(joueurs[0].touchesClavier)
}
```

I created this function but the keys don't change.

```
<div id = "dialog" title = "Changement de touche">Interface de changement de touches
        <br> Joueur 1 haut: <input id="j1h" type="text" size="1" maxlength="1" onkeydown="changerTouches(event)"/>
        <br> Joueur 1 bas: <input  id="j1b" type="text" size="1" maxlength="1" onkeydown="changerTouches(event)"/>
        <br> Joueur 1 gauche: <input id="j1g" type="text" size="1" maxlength="1" onkeydown="changerTouches(event)"/>
        <br> Joueur 1 droite: <input id="j1d" type="text" size="1" maxlength="1" onkeydown="changerTouches(event)"/>
        <br> <input type="submit" id="valider" value="valider"/>
      </div>
```

And that is a part of my html code.
So, can you please tell me how to get the keyCode of each input ?
Thanks you !

Comment: It looks like the keys are already nested inside of the `Joueurs` array; you would just need some code that modifies `Joueurs[...].touchesClavier`, or do you mean something else?

Comment: When the user clicks a button to add new custom binding, start listening for keypress. Store the key the user pressed in an array representing all keyboard characters that can be used to invoke specific operations. Every keypress, check each of those arrays for matches against the user input to determine the code to execute, if any.

Comment: yes I want to mean how to exactly allow these input ? I tried with a "prompt" but not worked...